# Migration is reporting errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Environment:

```
Windows 8.1
Ruby 2.1.5
rails 4.1.8
```

I have the following in one of my migration files:

```
class CreateVotesMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:votes) do |t|
      t.integer :item_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :vote
      t.integer :vote_weight
      t.string :vote_scope
      t.string :slug
      t.timestamps
  end
    add_index :votes, [:item_id, :user_id, :vote]
    add_index :votes, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

When I try to run the migration, I get the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateVotes
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Might be stemming from a routing error in your config/routes.rb file.  Try checking if you have a route that has that name and change it to match your table.

Comment: No there is no such thing in the routes.rb file

Answer (score 0):

Your filename need to match the Migration Class name. In your case,

```
class CreateVotesMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

the filename would need to be `2014xxxxxxxxxx_create_votes.rb`

Comment: The file name is 20141208220653_create_votes.rb there is no need for migration at the end of the file name

Comment: The file name has nothing to do with the failure. The only thing that counts is the numerical portion, which tells Rails the order to use for executing each of the migration files.